# Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'. Caused by "com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.7.0"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, unityads

I'm getting the next error when building a game in unity:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\andre.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dcabf090caecffb1d02527a5ebf491a6\com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.7.0\AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-54:58: AAPT: error: unexpected element < property > found in < manifest >< application >.

I've had more errors coming from the library "com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.7.0" and I cannot find how to remove any kind of calls to it. I'm using UnityAds to monetize my game using the Advertisement Legacy package. I need someone to tell me how to get rid of "com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.7.0" for good, and if you got some advice for the handling of ads in order to avoid any other errors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter the same issue with Unity Mediation Ads
Unity Advertisement with Mediation using dependency to Unity Ads 4.7.0 (released 4 Days ago) and I think i've enabled "Enable Resolution On Build"

try to use OverrideDependencies.xml to set the version to 4.6.1

1. Create OverrideDependencies.xml and put it under Assets/Editor
2. Paste this code

   `<dependencies> <androidPackages> <androidPackage spec="com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.6.1"/>   </androidPackages> <iosPods> <iosPod name="com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads" version="4.6.1"/> </iosPods> </dependencies>`